# How can married woman wearing mangalsutra can also wear rudraksha mala?

Tags: women, rudraksha

Rudraksha beads shouldn't touch metal except gold and silver. Then how can married woman wearing mangalsutra can also wear rudraksha mala?

Comment: I think they can wear it as wrist-band?

Comment: "Rudraksha beads shouldn't touch metal except gold and silver" - Where is it stated so?

Comment: https://www.ishashoppe.com/in/the-rudraksha-guide -> It is written in last section.

Comment: Ok it is talking about keeping the Rudraksha in a metal container but I had never heard about such an instruction that the Rudraksha must not come in touch with a metal. I wonder whether there is any scripture which have that rule. @VineetMimrot